# Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: php, return

I decided to launch a site that was created on the old php version. I have **php 7.4** and it gives on the screen:

**Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null**

*By referencing this line in the code:*

```
return $this->last_result[$y]?$this->last_result[$y]:null;
```

Please tell me how to change the code and remove this error?

```
.....
.....
        function get_row($query=null,$output=OBJECT,$y=0)
        {
            // Log how the function was called
            $this->func_call = "\$db->get_row(\"$query\",$output,$y)";
            // If there is a query then perform it if not then use cached results..
            if ( $query )
            {
                $this->query($query);
            }
            // If the output is an object then return object using the row offset..
            if ( $output == OBJECT )
            {
                return $this->last_result[$y]?$this->last_result[$y]:null;
            }
            // If the output is an associative array then return row as such..
            elseif ( $output == ARRAY_A )
            {
                return $this->last_result[$y]?get_object_vars($this->last_result[$y]):null;
            }
            // If the output is an numerical array then return row as such..
            elseif ( $output == ARRAY_N )
            {
                return $this->last_result[$y]?array_values(get_object_vars($this->last_result[$y])):null;
            }
            // If invalid output type was specified..
            else
            {
                $this->show_errors ? trigger_error(" \$db->get_row(string query, output type, int offset) -- Output type must be one of: OBJECT, ARRAY_A, ARRAY_N",E_USER_WARNING) : null;
            }
        }
.....
.....
```

Comment: Seems to me with this line is everything ok. You need to check the step after the `get_row (...)` was executed. I guess that `get_row ` returns the null value, and you trying to manage the result of work as an array. Could you provide the full trace of the error?

Comment: or you can just modify this line: 

`$this->last_result[$y]?$this->last_result[$y]:null` 

to 

`return isset($this->last_result) && isset($this->last_result[$y]?$this->last_result[$y]:null;`

Comment: @Alisher Gafurov I posted the code in full:  https://pastebin.com/L4E3RhsG  Error on line 139

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```php
return $this->last_result[$y]?$this->last_result[$y]:null;
```

Use:

```php
return $this->last_result[$y] ?? null;
```